# Calling functions on a state monad "Stack" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state, monads

We have the following types given by the task

```
newtype Trans state a = T {run :: state -> (a,state)}
type Stack a = Trans [Int] a
```

What I want is to write a function
1. push to put an Integer on the stack
2. pop to return and remove the highest object

i tried to google through state monads to understand them and I get the concept, but I cannot implement it with the given type structure.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right definition of `Stack`? I feel like it should be `type Stack a = Trans [a] a`.

Comment: And I believe the functions you're being asked to write are simple "pure" functions `state -> (a, state)`, and that you'll then learn about the State monad and how it can simplify series of such stack operations. You don't need to know anything about how the monad "works" in order to write these basic functions.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't know, maybe, but I don't think it makes a difference because we only have tasks that handle with Integers

Comment: `a` is the return value of an action on a `Stack`, so for example `push :: Int -> Stack ()` and `pop :: Stack Int`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I figured out:
            push :: Int -> Stack ()
            pop :: Stack Int
            add :: Stack () (takes two elements from stack, calculates the sum and puts it back on the stack).

i still dont get how to implement it tho. how to write it.

Comment: Are you given a `Monad` instance for `Trans state`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pop and push is rather straightforward:

```
push :: Int -> Stack ()
push x = T { run = \st -> ((), x : st) }

pop :: Stack (Maybe Int)
pop = T
  { run = \st -> case st of
      (x : xs) -> (Just x, xs)
      _ -> (Nothing, st)
  }
```

`pop` is type of `Maybe Int` because the stack can be empty. In that case we just return `Nothing`.
But what can we do with it? Well, not much without a `Monad` instance. Let's do one. We need `Functor` and `Applicative` instances first:

```
instance Functor (Trans st) where
  fmap f (T r) = T
    { run = \st -> 
        let (result, state) = r st
        in (f result, state)
    }

instance Applicative (Trans st) where
  pure a = T { run = \st -> (a, st) }
  (<*>) (T fr) (T r) = T
    { run = \st ->
        let (result, state) = r st
            (f, nextState) = fr state
        in (f result, nextState)
    }

instance Monad (Trans a) where
  (>>=) (T r) f = T
    { run = \st ->
        let (result, state) = r st
        in run (f result) state
    }
```

What does it give us? We can finally use our `pop` and `push` functions:

```
simpleStack :: Stack Int
simpleStack = do
  push 10
  push 20
  push 30
  Just x <- pop
  return x
```

And we can test it this way:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ fst $ run simpleStack []
```

Comment: To be fair, you can use `push` and `pop` without a `Monad` instance; it's just a lot more verbose :)

Comment: Is the `<*>` definition correct? It seems strange to me that `st` is applied to `r` and not `fr`. Usually the state is passed "left-to-right" and `fr` is the leftmost parameter.